# Querying a Dictionary with RavenDb

Tags: ravendb

I have a class defined as:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

based on the discussion I found here : http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/88ea52620021ed6c?pli=1

I can store an instance quite easily as :

```
//creation
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{               
    //now the student:
    var student = new Student();
    student.Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    student.Attributes["NIC"] = "studentsNICnumberGoesHere";               
    session.Store(student);
    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

However when I query it as below:

```
//Testing query on attribute
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    var result = from student in session.Query<Student>()
                 where
                     student.Attributes["NIC"] == "studentsNICnumberGoesHere"
                  select student;

    var test = result.ToList();                
}
```

I get the error "'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'." as shown:

[image]
How can I query based on a key in the dictionary?

Comment: Just verified that it works fine in unstable build 350 : http://builds.hibernatingrhinos.com/builds/ravendb-unstable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bug, it is fixed now.
Will be out in the next build, in about two hours