# Workaround for selectmany in ravendb using client api

Tags: ravendb

I have a ravendb class like such:

```
        public class Student
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string TopLevelProperty { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string,List<Dictionary<string, string>>> CategoryAttributes { get; set; }
        }
```

and a document like so: 
[image]

The following linq will not work due to a selectmany:

```
                test = (from student in session.Query()
                        from eduhistory in student.CategoryAttributes["EducationHistory"]
                        where eduhistory["StartYear"] == "2009"
                              select student).ToList();
```

How can I get all students where StartYear == 2009?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does it :

```
test = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery()
            .Where("CategoryAttributes.EducationHistory,StartYear:2009")
            .ToList();
```

Notice the comma rather than a dot after EducationHistory. This indicates that we are looking at the list to find a property in one of the items named StartYear. 
If I wanted greater than :

```
test = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery()
            .Where("CategoryAttributes.EducationHistory,StartYear:[2009 TO null]")
            .ToList();
```

etc etc.

Comment: For like I used Where("CategoryAttributes.EducationHistory,StartYear:*200*")

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
test = (from student in session.Query()
       where student.CategoryAttributes["EducationHistory"].Any(edu => edu["StartYear"]== "2009" )
       select student).ToList();
```

Comment: I get the error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.

Comment: I am using a build where this is fixed : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5800685/390330 However I am getting the same error in this query.