# RavenDB SelectMany alternative

Tags: c#, ravendb, linq

Am building a Photo gallery using Nancy and RavenDB
I have my model classes as below:

```
[JsonObject(IsReference=true)]
public class Album
{
    public Album()
    {
        this.Photos = new List<Photo>();
        this.Tags = new List<String>();
    }

    public String Id {get; set;}
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public String Path {get; set;}
    public DateTime ModifiedDate{get; set;}
    public IList<String> Tags {get; set;}
    public IList<Photo> Photos {get; set;}

}

    public class Photo
{
    public String Id {get; set;}
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public String Path {get; set;}
    public IList<String> Tags {get; set;}
    public Album Album {get; set;}
    public DateTime ModifiedDate{get; set;}
    public bool IsPrivate{get; set;}
}
```

And my attempt at map reduce index on Photo->Tags:

```
   public class TaggedPhotosIndex:AbstractIndexCreationTask<Album, TaggedPhotos>
    {
        public TaggedPhotosIndex()
        {
            Map = albums =>
                from a in albums
                from p in a.Photos
                from t in p.Tags
                select new TaggedPhotos
                {
                    Tag = t,
                    PhotoIds = new List<String> {p.Id}
                };
            Reduce = results => 
                from result in results
                group result by result.Tag into agg
                select new TaggedPhotos
                {
                    Tag = agg.Key,
                    PhotoIds = agg.SelectMany(a => a.PhotoIds).ToList()
                };
        }
    }

    public class TaggedPhotos
    {
        public String Tag {get; set;}
        public IList<String> PhotoIds {get; set;}
    }
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

Given an array of tags, I want to get all the Photo objects that have atleast one matching tag.

RavenDB doesn't allow SelectMany in the query and am out of ideas.

Found a solution (using LuceneQuery @ [Workaround for selectmany in ravendb using client api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973637/workaround-for-selectmany-in-ravendb-using-client-api)) , but looking forward for any other alternatives.

Comment: You dumped this in JabbR and bailed right away so little reluctant to help. You don't need to create a list of PhotoIds. Make the map completely flat.

Comment: Is each photo in a document? Or are all photos in the album document?  You have an Id on the Photo class, but you have embeded a IList<Photo> in your album.  One usually does it one way or the other, not both.  Did you mean to have an IList<string> of PhotoIds?

Comment: @MattJohnson Each Album is a document and the photos belong to that album. Photos are not documents on their own. If you see something wrong in classes, please suggest what needs to be changed

Comment: So what is a PhotoId then?  Not a document Id.  I assume somewhere in your system you would load a photo by its id, yes?  with the current structure, you have to load the whole album.

Comment: @MattJohnson I added it so that I would be able to delete or pick a spcific Photo by a unique identifier from an album ... If you have some time we can jump on to jabbr for a qcuik chat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some issues with your document structure that are going to make your query difficult.

- Queries are *designed* to return whole documents.  You are asking for a partial result from the document.  That can be done, but only if you store all fields in the index and project the results from there.  You give up the ACID guarantees of the document store, which is one of RavenDB's strongest features.
- You have a reference from `Photo` back to `Album` which would normally be embedded, causing a circular reference, except you are setting `[JsonObject(IsReference=true)]` to avoid that.  This may work for basic serialization within a single document, but it is meaningless when it comes to referencing a whole document back from a projected index value.  You've set up your own "chicken & egg" problem.
- You still are missing basic functionality one would expect from this problem domain.  Specifically, you should be able to load a single photo without having to load the whole album.

I ***strongly*** suggest that you put photos in their own documents.  Then you can have much simpler indexes and avoid the circular references.  In [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) terms, both `Photo` and `Album` are aggregates.  And a DDD aggregate == a RavenDB document.  You are currently modeling the Photo as an entity that is not an aggregate, but then you are asking for operations that one would only do against an aggregate - like the search.

If you were asking only "give me all *albums* that contain a photo tagged with one of these tags", then you would be ok.  But you're not asking for the albums, you're asking for the *photos*.

Assuming you did model it that way, Brett's answer is close - but has some extraneous stuff.  Here is a unit test showing a full implementation.  Posting on gist since it does not directly address the original question.  https://gist.github.com/4499724

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation. I was thinking Photo is not an aggregate as a Photo cannot exist without an album (in this domain).. Any comments on that?>

Comment: Photo *can* exist without an album.  You store photos, right?  Somewhere you have "add photo to album" going on, and it takes a photo.  If it's not an aggregate, you have to load the entire album, add a photo, then save the entire album.  Patching would let that happen server-side, but it still happens.

Comment: Ok. I was envisioning the Album - Photo relationship as a Folder - File type relation....A file cannot exist without the folder..Right?

Comment: Not true.  Most of the time you just work with files.  Just because you put them in a folder doesn't mean the file can't stand alone.  Perhaps within the filesystem, but that's just one context. What about when you load the file? Did you have to load the whole directory and all files in the directory? No.  Also - think about Driver and Car.  Would you say that a Driver can't exist without a Car?  Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

This one took me a while but I verified the solution below is working.

First, modify your Index and index result as shown below.

```
 public class TaggedPhotosIndex:AbstractIndexCreationTask<Photo, TaggedPhotos>
    {
        public TaggedPhotosIndex()
        {
            Map = photos =>                
                from p in Photos
                from t in p.Tags
                select new TaggedPhotos
                {
                    Tag = t,
                    PhotoId = p.Id
                };
        }
    }

    public class TaggedPhotos
    {
        public string Tag {get; set;}
        public string PhotoId {get; set;}
    }
```

Now that the index is created, here is how you query against it to get your photos.

```
var tagsToSearch = new List<string>(){"test1", "test2", "test3"};

var photoIds = documentSession.Query<TaggedPhotos, TaggedPhotoIndex>()
                               .Customize(x => x.Include<Photo>(p => p.Id))
                               .Where(x => x.Tag.In(tagsToSearch))
                               .Select(x => x.PhotoId)
                               .Distinct()
                               .ToArray();

// This doesn't actually make a second call as the photos are already loaded
// in the document session
var photos = documentSession.Load<Photo>(photoIds);
```

Based on the requirement

> Here is what I want to achieve:
>
> Given an array of tags, I want to get all the Photo objects that have
>   at least one matching tag.

I didn't see how album really tied into it all

Comment: Tried it .. Now there is no exception, but no Photos are returned. Will post a gist of what I am trying...

Comment: Take a look in Raven Studio at the index.  Execute the index and make sure documents are being loaded in the index.

Comment: This answer assumes you are storing photos in separate documents, and the OP said all photos are in an Album document.  Also, the reduce is not doing anything and can be removed.  Same goes for Distinct in the query.

Comment: @Matt I had to have distinct in the query since without it the same PhotoId was returned multiple times.  Then when I ran the second query the same photo was returned multiple times.  Also, I assumed these were stored separately for the same reasons you stated above.  Thanks for the update on the Map / Reduce